# Как запомнить данные, выбранные в <select> из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Логика следующая: у меня есть форма ввода данных состоящая из

```
 <select name="status">
      <option value="1">Не выбрано</option>
      <option value="2">Не женат</option>
      <option value="3">Не замужем</option>
      <option value="4">Встречаюсь</option>
      <option value="5">Помолвлен</option>
      <option value="6">Женат</option>
      <option value="7">Замужем</option>
      <option value="8">В гражданском браке</option>
      <option value="9">Влюблён</option>
      <option value="10">Всё сложно</option>
      <option value="11">В активном поиске</option>
    </select>
```

Мне нужно чтобы данные из `select` отправились в БД с названием `users` в поле `status`
Затем чтобы поле `select` запомнило значение из БД и выводило не первое значение из select, а соответствующее значение, которое хранится в БД

И, к примеру можно было вывести данное значение в формате:

```
  <?php echo 'Ваш статус' . 'соответствующее значение из БД'; ?>
```

Вот весь код:

```
 <?php
$save = $_POST;
if( isset($save['do_login']) )
{

mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `users` SET `name`='".$save['name']."',  `date`='".$save['date']."', `status`='".$save['status']."' WHERE id=$id ");

echo '<div style="background-color: green; color: white; font-weight: light; font-size: 17px;">Данные сохранены!</div>';

}
?>

<form action="/new.php" method="POST">

<?php 
$data_save = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=$id");
if( mysqli_num_rows($data_save) <= 0 ) 
{
    echo 'Unexpected error!';
} else 
{
  $get_data_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_save);
}
?>

<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value="<?php echo $get_data_user['name'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="date" placeholder="date" value="<?php echo $get_data_user['date'] ?>">
<p>Статус</p>
<select name="status">
  <option value="1">Не выбрано</option>
  <option value="2">Не женат</option>
  <option value="3">Не замужем</option>
  <option value="4">Встречаюсь</option>
  <option value="5">Помолвлен</option>
  <option value="6">Женат</option>
  <option value="7">Замужем</option>
  <option value="8">В гражданском браке</option>
  <option value="9">Влюблён</option>
  <option value="10">Всё сложно</option>
  <option value="11">В активном поиске</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="do_login">Войти</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select отправляется так же, как и input. Т.е. доступ к выбранному идет по `$_POST['status']`
Чтобы при выборе данных из БД выбиралось это значение, нужно соответствующему полю присвоить selected. Сделать это можно с помощью jQuery/js. На jQuery это выглядит так:

```
$('select option[value=' <?php echo $user['user_status']; ?>']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: Можете подсказать куда данный код вставить и как

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень надо просто я новичок